# Why can't I handle fatal errors in CakePHP 2.x with PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I'm having a strange problem in CakePHP where my `AppExceptionRenderer` is not being triggered for fatal and parse errors (`E_ERROR` and `E_PARSE`) when using PHP 5.2.  The exact same code on my development machine (PHP 5.5) works fine.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up tracking it down to what appears to be a bug in PHP 5.2 where a call to `new SplFileInfo()` strangely resets the fatal error information that normally exists inside `error_get_last()`.

My fix was to tweak Cake's default `App::shutdown()` function by moving the `_checkFatalError()` call up above the `Cache::write()` calls.

So the result was this...

```
public static function shutdown() {
    // For some weird reason on PHP 5.2 the SplFileInfo call made in Cache::write 
    // resets error_get_last() which means we can't trap fatal/parse errors.  
    // Small workaround is to check for errors *before* doing the caching thing
    self::_checkFatalError();

    if (self::$_cacheChange) {
        Cache::write('file_map', array_filter(self::$_map), '_cake_core_');
    }
    if (self::$_objectCacheChange) {
        Cache::write('object_map', self::$_objects, '_cake_core_');
    }
    // self::_checkFatalError();
}
```

Perhaps it may help someone else out there someday.  :-)

Comment: Report this as an issue on Github to get it fixed in the core.